# class "responsive" in css and bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

Is there a standard class "responsive"? I see using it like "img-responsive" and "table-responsive".

I did not find any standard reference. Any information on using "responsive" as a standard class would be helpful.

Comment: No, it's not standardized. You could call it `img-snorgleblaster` if you want, it'd just be a little less understandable when you go looking in the CSS two years later.

Answer (score 1):

There's no css class "responsive" in bootstrap. 'img-responsive', 'table-responsive' are for responsive image and table. Adding 'table-responsive' to table, scrollbar shows up below table on small devices.